# ExpressionEngine source control via git

Tags: php, git, version-control, content-management-system, expressionengine

Im stuck with supporting some ExpressionEngine sites and I'm trying to check this CMS into source control.

I am failing since I cannot see a way to decouple the database from the templates and other structures. I'd like to be able to version control aspects in the CMS including content and channel creation as well as template creation and modification.

Comment: Andrew, consider posting on http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/ for more attention from the EE experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say that EE is a legacy system, they actually just pushed out their v2.8 a few days ago and have been updating the system for years.

If you're familiar with WordPress, the process really shouldn't be too different. You need to save templates as files and version control those along with system files. You're most likely not going to be version-controlling the database similar to the way you wouldn't be doing that with WordPress.

Simply turning to Google would probably give you hundreds of answers about how to do this but I'll leave you with what I consider to be the most definitive reading on the subject:

http://devot-ee.com/articles/item/version-control-for-expressionengine-using-git-part-1

Comment: everyone here seems to be missing the basic point of my question: In expressionEngine it seems you cannot source control the structure of the site as in other CMSes. For example if i create Channels and Field Groups, They are stored in the DB. 99% of CMSes do not store any structural element of a sites information architecture in the DB. Thus enabling source control and decoupling the database.

Comment: There is a clear and concise differnce between content structures and content itself. A structure being a Channel or a Field.

Comment: Right- and that clear and concise difference wasn't specified in your original question since you seemed more interested in bashing EE than actually writing a meaningful question. You and your team may want to investigate using http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-editor. It's not going to take you 100% of the way to version controlling channels and fields but it will let you export and import field groups between developers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved the templates as text files? Once you do that, you can then just backup the template folder. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/templates_as_files.html

Comment: although that still depends on having a database in the first place. If we are working as a team we should be able to be TOTALLY separated from a database...

Basically we usually work with different CMS systems based on newer architecture that allow for source control AKA October CMS, Laravel, Wordpress...

Comment: It seems so many EE developers take the route of working on a live server using FTP. This is defiantly a massive problem and something we want to avoid at all costs...

Comment: yes, that's true. it is hard to set up source control on EE. I guess I don't understand what you mean when you say separate completely from the database. Wordpress uses a database, doesn't it?